# GeoDjango - Json Data Migrations - Invalid Syntax

Tags: python-3.x

I am loading json data from `migrations`. So in my `migrations` file I have put the following code

```
from django.db import migrations

from django.db import migrations
import json
from django.contrib.gis.geos import fromstr
from pathlib import Path

DATA_FILENAME = 'data.json'
def load_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Shop = apps.get_model('shops', 'Shop')
    jsonfile = Path(__file__).parents[2] / DATA_FILENAME

    with open(str(jsonfile)) as datafile:
        objects = json.load(datafile)
        for obj in objects['elements']:
            try:
                objType = obj['type']
                if objType == 'node':
                    tags = obj['tags']
                    name = tags.get('name','no-name')
                    longitude = obj.get('lon', 0)
                    latitude = obj.get('lat', 0)
                    location = fromstr(f'POINT({longitude} {latitude})', srid=4326)
                    Shop(name=name, location = location).save()
            except KeyError:
                pass     

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('shops', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [migrations.RunPython(load_data)]
```

But it is giving me error which i don't have idea - The error is in this line  - `location = fromstr(f'POINT({longitude} {latitude})', srid=4326)`

Error -

```
File "/project/geo_django/shops/migrations/0002_auto_20190315_1120.py", line 26
    location = fromstr(f'POINT({longitude} {latitude})', srid=4326)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using `Python 3.5.2`

Comment: It's just a plain python syntax error, nothing to do with django, geodjango, migrations etc (tags removed).

Answer (score 2):

`f'strings` are introduce in `python 3.6` [pep-0498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)(see the Python-Version)

Change this line

```
location = fromstr(f'POINT({longitude} {latitude})', srid=4326)
```

with this -

```
location = fromstr('POINT({} {})'.format(longitude, latitude), srid=4326)
```